# Create a licensed Office user using AzureAD

Tags: excel, powershell, ms-office, office365

Is it possible to create new users and licenses to Office 365 using Azure Active Directory Powershell v2?

One of our services require Excel to be running on the server (I know Microsoft don't support Excel running on the server-side, but it currently works decently enough).

We're trying to automate the provisioning of these servers since it's currently a manual process - mainly around create new users / licenses for Office and activating Office.

I've managed to connect to the Office 365 account using Azure AD for Powershell (note that we don't actually use Azure, everything is hosted on AWS) and can see all the different users, groups, etc, however I have no prior experience with this, and am looking for any guidance on the how to achieve the following via Powershell:

- create a new user
- assign a new Office license for that user
- activate Office with that new user

Answer (score 1):

Yes, thats possible. But need to user the MSOnline Powershell Module. Here you have **Set-MSOLUserLicense** to assign licenses.

Comment: That's a deprecated product, right?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/?view=azureadps-1.0

Microsoft recommend using the newer version (Azure AD for Powershell v2) as per the link above.

Comment: You are right of course. I constantly use the "old" module and it works without any problems.
Using the new AzureAD-Module you use Set-AzureADUserLicense to achieve the same as the old Set-MSOLUserLicense.
Details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Azuread/Set-AzureADUserLicense?view=azureadps-2.0